# How to fix: rendered="false" on a selectoption causes further selectoptions within the repeat to not render

Tags: visualforce, selectlist, rendered, repeat, selectoption

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="item" id="myRepeater">
    ...
    <apex:selectList required="" value="{!item.newValue}" id="mySelectlist" multiselect="false" size="1" style="border:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance: none;padding-right: 30px;color:rgb(31, 73, 125);">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue=" " itemLabel=" " rendered="{!item.renderWhenBlank}"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!myGlobalSelectOptions}" />
    </apex:selectList>
    ...
</repeat
```

Scenario:

- 10 items in myList.
- each item (Class) has a boolean called renderWhenBlank. This is used to render a blank Option/Value at the top of the
- only 1 item in the middle of the list (myList[5]) has a false in this
  boolean.

Issue:

- When the 10 render the top 5 SelectLists have a rendered SelectOption at the top of " " (CORRECT);
- and the 6th does not have the top SelectOption (CORRECT);
- **but the remaining selectLists 7-10 do not have a top SelectOption. The moment there is a rendered = "False" the next items in the list also incorrectly rendered="false" This is what we want fixed**

Secondary Question: Or is this a Salesforce bug!

possible work arounds:
javascript updating the style of our blank extra selectOption. Or creating a new variable in our class of type List and not using a global variable (and removing the solo selectOption).

Comment: would you re-frame your question with a screenshot and relevant code to understand this.

Comment: The code looks like it should work, so I presume it's a bug. You'll probably want to localize your options `{!item.mySelectOptions}`, which you'll probably want to render as two separate lists (one with and without the blank option) stored in static variables for performance.

Comment: Yes , I tried  to solve your problem, I faced same issue .

Answer (score 0):

The following works just fine:

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="myExample">


    <apex:form >

    <apex:selectList required="" value="{!selectedValue}" id="mySelectlist" multiselect="false" size="1" >
        <apex:selectOption itemValue=" " itemLabel=" " rendered="true"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!theOptions}" />
    </apex:selectList>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class myExample{

    public string selectedValue {get;set;}

    public SelectOption[] theOptions{
        get{
        return New SelectOption[]{
            New SelectOption('a','a'),
            New selectOption('b','b')
        };
        }
    }


}
```

Start with the above, get it working then add your other code around it to see what breaks it.

Alternately you can use a repeat to populate the `<apex:selectOption>` for each one you want instead of using the `<apex:selectOptions>`

**Rendered = true**

[image]

**Rendered = false**

[image]

**Note** You can also simply add a blank selectOption to the list of selectOptions in the Apex class instead of doing it in the markup if your flow allows it

Comment: Yes this does work with a hardcoded rendered = true.
But we want it dynamically rendered within each iteration of the repeat.
and when it gets to an iteration of the repeat and rendered = false, every iteration following that is also rendered = false whether we like it or not.

Comment: Confirmed this to be the case. If within a repeat once the rendered value = false it will not display again.

Comment: Sorry what are you confirming:
That the problem exists or that you have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer, as per SFDCFOX's comment above, it is a Salesforce Bug.

**Our ultimate work around:**
We chose to use a new variable in our class "List myOptions" which rendered separately for each iteration of the repeat.

I only worry that this increases our viewstate???

**Our alternate solution which caused us css issues:**
We created 2 option lists and rendered the desired one based on our boolean item.renderWhenBlank.